# Foo() vs this.Foo()

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a co-worker who uses a C# refactoring tool. The tool for some reason perfers:

```
this.Foo()
```

over

```
Foo()
```

Now we've asked him to turn it off simply because it's annoying to have all the code re-written automatically, but that's not the point.

Am I missing something, or is this just wrong? Why on earth would I want `this.Foo()`?

Comment: Voting to close this question as subjective and argumentative. There's no definitive right answer here, it all comes down to opinions and style. Basically it is a disguised poll.

Comment: Note that if you are attempting to use an extension method (say your class implements IEnumerable and you want to call this.Count()) then you are required to use "this." to trigger the extension method lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers here point out, this is largely a matter of style.

Many times a call to `Foo()` would be unambiguous without the `this.`, but there are times where it might add clarity.  For example:

```
EventHandler foo = GetEventHandlerFoo();
EventHandler baz = GetEventHandlerBar();
foo();
this.Bar();
baz();
```

In this case, the `this.` prefix helps to make the method invocation stand out from the delegate invocations.

Is this *necessary*?  No, and Lasse V. Karlsen correctly points out that the `this.` is just a surrogate for a naming convention that makes it unambiguous.

But I find that I will frequently use the `this.Foo` prefix on local *properties* for a similar reason, where again it is more a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it, use it.

If you don't want to use it, don't use it.

There's no right answer here.

If for some reason you have a naming convention where the name alone isn't enough to determine whether you're looking at a local variable, a method parameter, an instance field, a property, or a method, you should fix the naming convention, instead of prefixing local fields with `this.` to distinguish them from local variables.

Answer (score 2):

I think this comes down to a question of syntax vs. semantics.  The argument for `this.Foo()` is it very explicitly denotes exactly what Foo() is and where it came from.  There's no wondering if it was an argument passed in to a method, or a static class declared who-knows-where.  It's a method on the current object, period.  Anything less and you're giving up clear semantics in favor of tighter syntax.

The obvious argument against it:  Mouse-over and ctrl+click.

Comment: If the only argument against it is mouse-over, I would actually be in favor of it, because you should be able to read the code on-screen without going source-hunting with the mouse. The naming convention would fix that.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  This is one of those "yes-I-have-a-preference-but-not-so-strong-that-I'm-willing-to-participate-in-a-holy-war-over-it-in-the-midst-of-a-standards-and-conventions-meeting" issues.  I largely fell in love with c# for it's concise, meaningful syntax compared to what I was accustomed to.  A little smidgen of verbosity isn't necessarily a bad thing though.

Comment: Yep, agree, and that's the problem with this question, it all comes down to choice and opinion. I'm going to vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a style thing.  Sometimes people think it makes the code more clear -- apparently some people find it helpful to be explicit about the target of a method invocation.  Personally, I find the spurious use of `this` to be distracting.

Answer (score 1):

This example demonstrates how the `this` keyword can be used to explicitly describe a variable's scope:

```
class Item
{
    int id;

    public Item (int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a horrible naming convention anyway. I don't use `this.` but I'm not going to tell people to not use it, but I would seriously tell you (or anyone else) not to use that naming convention. Fix the naming convention problem, and the question of `this.` vs. not `this.` becomes, again, a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen In this example, to demonstrate your preferred convention, what name would you use for the parameter instead of `id`?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I do agree that it's not the best convention, but some IDEs, for instance NetBeans, automatically generate constructor using it...

Comment: @Lasse: Thanx for sharing .. Could you tell me please how to name fields and paramters ?

Comment: I like to prefix fields with `_`.  so `int _id;` in that case.  Again, treading FIRMLY into the realm of subjective opinion...  I tend to do what you're doing when setting auto properties in a constructor, where there is no field.

Comment: For what it's worth, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I always use `this.` since it explicitly shows where the thing is.  I don't even use a refactoring tool to do it.  I type it by hand.